# how can i reset all my git commands for my react app and start from new?

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I've been having trouble pushing to github because im new to it. I have multiple repositories dedicated to the same React app I have and it's been really messy with all these seemingly random git commands I've been putting in because I keep messing up.

I was toying with git stuff previously, but now I have an empty github repo that I want to push to. How can I reset everything I did earlier and start from square one to simply push my React app to github?

In cmd, I write all the very basic steps that Github tells you when you first create a repo. This is the output:

```
C:\Users\zzzz\Documents\gap>git init 
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/zzzz/Documents/gap/.git/

C:\Users\zzzz\Documents\gap>git add README.md

C:\Users\zzzz\Documents\gap>git commit -m "first commit"
interactive rebase in progress; onto 2cb97d3
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 9bdce5c first commit
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   pick 705699b Trigger rebuild # empty
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '2cb97d3'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)       

nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\zzzz\Documents\gap>git branch -M master
fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'

C:\Users\zzzz\Documents\gap>git remote add origin https://github.com/simonshm5/gap-data-science-covid.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

C:\Users\zzzz\Documents\gap>git push -u origin master
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

I don't know what any of these errors mean or how to fix them. When I run `npm start`, my program works perfectly fine on `localhost`. Now, I just want to push to Github and deploy it on Github pages.

Comment: You are fooling around in the middle of an interactive rebase. Stop it. You need to say `git rebase --abort`, then see if your actual files are harmed. If not, throw the invisible `.git` folder away. You've done enough damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this errors because you already initialize git for this project in that folder. So, first you have to delete that git file in your folder. Go to your project folder and delete folder called ".git". If you can't see that folder make sure you turn on **show hidden files,folders and disks**. After that you can follow this steps: https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line